# Save additional data on model-creation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I got the following problem:

I need to save an item called `InvoicePosition` with a  `Product` in my controller. Each `Product` can have `ProductAttributes`.

Although I am using the `Product`-Class I am **not** saving this product as relation in a database, but I use this class to "normalize" the input. Actually the data goes to a JSON-field in the database.

So:

**InvoicePosition**

```
- id (incr.)
- customer_id (integer)
- quantity (integer)
- product (JSON)
```

To save this position in my controller, I am doing this:

```
<?php
$product = new Product($position['product']);

$invoice->positions()->create([
    'quantity'           => $position['factor'],
    'product'            => $product,
]);
```

This works fine. To get the `Product` later, I am using this accessor:

```
public function getProductAttribute($value)
{
    $value                     = (array)json_decode($value);
    $product                = new Product($value);
    $product                = $product->with('productAttributes')
        ->first();
    return $product;
}
```

This is working fine, too - I am getting an instance of `App\Product`:

```
=> App\Product {#1228
     id: 1,
     price: 1.99,
     productAttributes: [...]
```

Now I got a problem: I need to save **additional information** in the JSON-field of the product. In my case, I need to duplicate the `productAttributes` of each `Product`.

So I thought about something like this in the controller:

```
<?php
$product = new Product($position['product']);

$product->productAttributes()->map(function($attribute){
  $attribute->original = $attribute;
  return $attribute;
});

$invoice->positions()->create([
    'quantity'           => $position['factor'],
    'product'            => $product,
]);
```

But now my accessor does not reflect these changes, as `App\Product` includes `App\ProductAttribute` but not the additional field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers)

```php
class ProductObserver
{
    // performed when product is updated
    // alternatively, use saved(Product $product), or both (depending on what you're after)
    public function updated(Product $product) 
    {
        // duplicate your product attributes here
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the additional value, even if stored as JSON, is not returned using the accessor.

Comment: @SPQRInc Did you add it to `$fillable` on your model?

Comment: Yes, but without any success.